# remove multiple files using terminal?

Tags: file, terminal, directory

I want to delete two specific folders and a file from my current directory:

```
 1. settings/
 2. models/
 3. file.txt
```

How do I remove these using single command in terminal?

Comment: Which OS and/or shell are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rm -rf settings/ models/ file.txt
```

Comment: Can you define what r and f are for?

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @jcpennypincher is correct for unix system since folders are functionally treated like files.
`r` stand for "recursive": delete files in directory and in its subdirectories and in its subdirectories etc...,
`f` stand for "force".
[man rm](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm)

If you are looking for the same solution in windows (command prompt) it can't be done in just one command: files and folder in windows have different rappresentations. You have to use `del` for files and `rmdir` command for folders.